# share wild card on facebook in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have implement wildcard api in my app. wildcard make a card which can be presented. But i need it to share on facebook please help me to share this card on facebook.

```
[Card getFromUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.autonews.com/article/20150820/OEM06/150829990/ford-patents-autonomous-vehicle-with-reconfigurable-seats"]
          completion:^(Card *card, NSError *error)
     {
         if(card)
         {
            //[self presentCard:card animated:YES completion:nil];
         }
     }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Card getFromUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.autonews.com/article/20150820/OEM06/150829990/ford-patents-autonomous-vehicle-with-reconfigurable-seats"]
          completion:^(Card *card, NSError *error)
     {
         if(card)
         {
            [self presentCard:card animated:YES completion:nil];
         }
     }];
```

**Wildcard will automatically give post feature.Configure accounts(facebook, twitter e.t,c) in setting, it will automatically show sharing option. if accounts is not configure it doesn't show sharing option.**